# Share files and devices using Belkin N150

Tags: network-shares, wireless-router, file-sharing

I have a Belkin N150, wireless modem+router.

I have connected my desktop with a LAN cable and my laptop uses Wi-Fi.

My desktop is connected to External Hard Drive and Printer and is always switched on.

Is it possible that I can access desktop's drive, external drive connected to it and printer also. If so how can I do that.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 on both desktop and laptop.

Comment: Seriously, If someone is giving a negative, atleast tell the reason, so I can more careful next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to enable the file and printer sharing under Control Panel/Advanced Sharing Settings. Full path: `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings`.

Once the file sharing is enabled go to `Computer`, right click on the drive you want to share, in this case the drive corresponding to your external harddrive and go to the `Sharing` tab. Under Sharing click `Advanced sharing` and check `share this folder`. Once sharing is enabled give the folder a name, in this case I would give it the drive letter, eg. E and click `OK`.

For the printer sharing go to `Devices and Printers`, right click on the printer you want to share and click on `Printer Properties`. Under Printer Properties click on `Sharing` and check `Share this printer`, give it a name and accept the changes.

On your other computer go to `Computer`, right click anywhere, choose `Add a network location` and select `Choose a custom network location`. Under the `Internet or network address` write your other computer name/shared drive name, eg. MyComputer/E. Click next and finalize the setup.

To add the printer go to `Devices and Printers`, right click anywhere and choose `Add printer` and choose `Add a network printer`. If your sharing was done properly the shared printer should appear in a list, select it, install the drivers and you're done.

Comment: Everything seems fine after following your instructions. But I'm getting data transfer speeds of about 1.5 MB / sec. Is this normal ?

Comment: @Nikhil I am not sure about the speeds you should be getting but you can trying finding some tool that can test your home network connection and see if some packets are getting lost. Unfortunately  I don't have any recommendation for such a software but you can try asking about one with another question on this forum.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest ways to share files are:

- Use AIM and send files (not secure though)
- Set up Windows for sharing using shared folders and do this using instructions in the other answer (Not easy way)
- Use a program like Teamviewer (free) and set it up so that you can open it automatically from other computer and already have username and password.

If you want to share the printer, then you must set up Windows for file and printer sharing using other person's instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed when I share files with my Linksys router I can use my computers network names and if I need to know their IP I can go in DOS and ping it's network name and get the IP... but when I use the same Belkin N150 router you mention, network sharing becomes a bit more difficult. When you ping a network name on the Belkin router it gives a weird IP and adds .Belkin to the end of the network name. I can find the ACTUAL IP address of the computer by logging in the router and looking at the DHCP client list. If I connect to a network share typing out the whole IP address (not convenient at all) it will connect and I can continue doing things like VNC and network file transfers just as I did with the Linksys. I am confused as to why this is or how to change it but so far this is what I know. The other answers on this page are just a bunch of mumbo jumbo about how to configure windows for sharing or ways to share without actually sharing properly over the network (like transferring files over AIM.. weird). That's not really the issue with the Belkin N150 and using third party software is not ideal. The issue is that the Belkin N150 does network sharing and network shares in it's own unique way.